# How to Exclude a Row in Look up Field in Sharepoint Form?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

Assume i have SP List A and SP List B. 
in SP list B i have a look up field which uses SP list A as Data Source.
SP List A have two Fields (i.e. Field 1 : Project Name, Field 2: Project Status)

I need to exclude Entries with Project Status as "Closed" in look up.

is there any way to Exclude this in infopath form or something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that in MS infopath we can filter out the content in Lookup by

right click the Look up field  field properties in **Data** tab select data source from add
 button and apply filter in forecoming Wizards